# What are the implications of the higher dpi screen on the iPad 3 for assets?

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

Obviously Apple just released the [new iPad](http://www.apple.com/ipad/). As far as developers are concerned, what are the implications for adding new assets to support the retina and non-retina displays across iPad models? Is it the same as the @2x model implemented on the iPhone 4 and 4S?

If I have foo.png what name would I call its different size versions so it worked in a universal app across all iOS devices?

Comment: foo.png, foo@2x.png, foo~ipad.png, foo@2x~ipad.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be solved by doing what you said, `@2x` but with a device modifier, since they have doubled the number of pixels. You will probably be writing `myimage@2x~ipad.png`.

> Applications running in iOS 4 should now include two separate files
>   for each image resource. One file provides a standard-resolution
>   version of a given image, and the second provides a high-resolution
>   version of the same image. The naming conventions for each pair of
>   image files is as follows:

```
Standard: <ImageName><device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
High resolution: <ImageName>@2x<device_modifier>.<filename_extension>
```

> The `<ImageName>` and `<filename_extension>` portions of each name
>   specify the usual name and extension for the file. The
>   `<device_modifier>` portion is optional and contains either the string
>   `~ipad` or `~iphone`. You include one of these modifiers when you want to
>   specify different versions of an image for iPad and iPhone. The
>   inclusion of the `@2x` modifier for the high-resolution image is new and
>   lets the system know that the image is the high-resolution variant of
>   the standard image.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html